# ¿Como quitar comillas en un array?

Tags: javascript

Necesito quitar del siguiente string las comillas que estan antes del '[' de geolocalizacion y el que esta despues de ']' al cierre. Pero no encuntro el modo de hacerlo. (Los marco en negrita para ver si de ese modo se nota mejor cuales son los que quiero quitar.

```
{"feriadoTipoId":3,"fecha":"2022-06-19","descripcion":"Carnaval UpdatedFrom local","geolocalizacion": " [{"geolocalizacionId": 22, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 5, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 24, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 23, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 1, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 3, "estado": "A"}] "  }
```

Como podria hacer para quitarlas?

Lo que necesito hacer es enviar este JSON pero como String (esto ya lo tengo hecho), debido a que despues hay un servicio que toma esto y utiliza la informacion necesaria.  Pero a su vez este String/Json debe cumplir con cierto criterio. De ahi que necesito sacar especificamente esas dos comillas solamente.

Intente hacer con replace() pero no tengo el resultado esperado.

De ante mano gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Hola Ema, en tu pregunta esta faltando un poco más de contexto. ¿Como estas procesando actualmente esa cadena? Aparentemente es un JSON ¿sabes como transformar un JSON a objeto? Utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar esta información en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, agregue mas informacion, espero que sea util para hayar la solucion.

Comment: pero el string que nos has compartido, no es un string json valido ... usaste algo para imprimirlo??? o es tal cual esta en la publicacion???

Comment: genial!!! intentaste el replace, mostranos como lo intentaste, y el resultado que obtuviste...

Comment: @gbianchi hay cosas que me dejan con dudas sobre lo intentado ... o mejor dicho de donde viene la data como esto al final: `***"***}"`

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover es valido, hice la prueba por postman (quitando la comilla antes del "[" y despues del "]") y me dio un resultado exitoso. El unico problema son esas dos comillas

Comment: Listo te dejo la respuesta en un toque.

Comment: @gbianchi Ahi corregi el string json de la pregunta. los "*" aparecian porque lo habia marcado en negritas y quedo de ese modo, pero para mayor claridad los saque, de todos modos lo importante son la comilla antes del corchete y despues del cierre del mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira aqui lo correcto puede ser implementar REGEX no soy un experto pero lo solucionaria de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Tu cadena JSON original
var jsonString = '{"feriadoTipoId":3,"fecha":"2022-06-19","descripcion":"Carnaval UpdatedFrom local","geolocalizacion": " [{"geolocalizacionId": 22, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 5, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 24, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 23, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 1, "estado": "A"},{"geolocalizacionId": 3, "estado": "A"}] "  }';

// Utilizando replace para quitar las comillas antes y después de la geolocalización
var jsonStringWithoutQuotes = jsonString.replace(/"(\s*\[.*?\]\s*)"/g, '$1');

// Mostrar el resultado
console.log(jsonStringWithoutQuotes);
```

Como veras si implemento replace como indicas que intentaste.

He verificado la salida aqui (string json): https://jsonformatter.org/#google_vignette

Bueno aqui lo importante tambien es dar una explicacion completa de que hace el REGEX que se implementa:

- /: Esto marca el inicio de la expresión regular.
- ": Busca una comilla doble al principio de la geolocalización.
- (\s*[.*?]\s*): Este es un **grupo de captura** que incluye:

  - \s*: Cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco (cero o más).
  - [ y ]: Corchetes, que son caracteres especiales en las expresiones regulares, por lo que deben ser escapados con .
  - .*?: Cualquier carácter (.) cero o más veces (*), pero de manera no codiciosa debido al ?. Esto asegura que coincida con la menor cantidad posible de caracteres hasta encontrar el siguiente corchete de cierre.
  - \s*: Cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco (cero o más).
- ": Busca una comilla doble al final de la geolocalización.
- /: Esto marca el final de la expresión regular.
- g: Esto indica que la búsqueda debe ser global, es decir, que debe buscar todas las coincidencias en la cadena, no solo la primera.

finalizamos con `$1`, aqui es donde se guardara las coincidencia.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y la ayuda. La verdad estoy poco familiarizado con las expresiones regulares, por esa razón no supe como resolverlo. Gracias también por la info, esto resuelve el problema que tenia y necesitaba solucionar ahora. Saludos!

Answer (score -2):

en cualquier lenguaje de programación encuentras la función "replace" con la cual puedes buscar el string que necesitas y reemplazarlo por otro.

Por ejemplo, en C#:

```
string originalString = "Hello, World!";
string newString = originalString.Replace(",", ";");
Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Esto lo haces dos veces con el "[ y luego con ]", los remplazas con [ y ] respectivamente.

Comment: la pregunta es sobre javascript...

Comment: Por favor deja que muestren lo que intentaron y responde en el mismo lenguaje de programación que la pregunta.